# Record not insert in the end of access file with delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, ado

Im reading one Access database with ADO and copying the data to another with the same structure. My problem is that sometime, it dont insert at the end of the file.

```
  DM1.ADOConnectionReadAccess.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' + 'User ID=Admin;' +
      'Data Source=' + Directory + 'Courbe\Courbe Actuel.mdb' + ';' +
      'Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";' + 'Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;';
  DM1.ADOConnectionReadAccess.Connected := true;

  DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.CommandText := 'select * from Courbe_Reservoir order by DateHeure';
  DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.Active := true;
```

So i read my database and order it by DateTime. Now, i have to do some change on the data when i copy it to the new database.

```
  DM1.ADOConnectionCopyExcel.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' +
      'User ID=Admin;' +
      'Data Source=' + Directory + 'Courbe\Part of curve.mdb' + ';' +
      'Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";' +
      'Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;';
  DM1.ADOConnectionCopyExcel.Connected := true;


  while not DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.Eof do
    begin
      Date2 := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('DateHeure').AsDateTime;   
      DernierDebit := DernierDebit  + DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('DebitRes').AsFloat / 1000;


      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.CommandText :=
                              'INSERT INTO Courbe_Reservoir' + ' VALUES (:DateHeure1, ' +
                              ':Niveau, ' +        //niveau
                              ':DebitRes, ' +      //débit entrée
                              ':PH, ' +            //ph
                              ':Chlore, ' +        //Chlore
                              ':Turbidite, ' +     //Turbidité
                              ':Temp, ' +          //température
                              '0, ' +              //Consommation l/min
                              '0, ' +              //Log
                              ':DernierDebit, ' +  //Consommation journalière
                              '0, 0, 0, '''', '''', ''''' + ')';
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('DateHeure1').Value := Date1;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('Niveau').Value := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('Niveau').AsFloat;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('DebitRes').Value := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('DebitRes').AsFloat;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('PH').Value := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('PH').AsFloat;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('Chlore').Value := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('Chlore').AsFloat;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('Turbidite').Value := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('Turbidite').AsFloat;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('Temp').Value := DM1.ADODataSetReadAccess.FieldByName('Temp').AsFloat;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Parameters.ParamByName('DernierDebit').Value := DernierDebit;
      DM1.ADOCommandCopyExcel.Execute;
     end;
```

When i check the new database, i got the following result in the image :
[image: Part of access database]

As you can see, i got a gap in time because i got a record for each minute. The missing record in the image are located elsewhere in the database.

In the end, i want to know why its not show in the same order i insert them. The bottom line is i want to export the new access database (.mdb) to an excel file using an export command but the export command seem to take the access file and copy it to excel as is, so no way to order it because the export. I dont want to go throught all the record again with a select and insert it in excel one after the other.

Right now, i got a file with almost 180 000 record and i need to split it per month, so the new database will have around 44 000 record.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Insertion location is not defined in most databases — the database engine has the liberty to store data wherever it deems most appropriate. It might choose to add records to the end of the table, but it might also choose to reuse space vacated by previously deleted records.

If you want results in a particular order, then indicate that in your selection query, typically by including an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: So, if i understand, i will not have a choice to insert row by row my data from ms-access to ms-excel since i cannot make sure that the access database in not order properly to begin with.

Comment: The stange thing is that i dont have previously deleted record in my database because i got an empty table (that has been compacted) before inserting data.

Comment: I would expect you can create your spreadsheet rows in whatever order you want; you haven't shown the code you use for that. Besides, Excel supports sorting, too.

Comment: I would have use the following command to export access to excel without needing to go throught all the row myself. If there is no wait to make sure that the data are in the same order i insert them, i will have no choice to do as you told me, by inserting the row in the excel file one by one.
     //export the data  LAccess := CreateOleObject('Access.Application');
     LAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet( acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName, ExcelFileName, True);

Comment: By the way, i dont want to client to need to sort the file because im sure he wil forget to do it and can cause other problem in the future for them.

Comment: There is no implicit order for a query, so it stands to reason that there would be no implicit order to a generic export command, either. You can either run a query with the order you want, and use that query to generate the spreadsheet yourself, or you can use Access's default export and then update the spreadsheet yourself. Either way involves writing code, but that should be no problem since writing code is why we're all here in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the records *should* appear in the "order" you inserted them due to the nature of .mdb files (in a multi-user db this would be chaos to be anything else!). Try adding an autonumber if you don't already have one -- you can then double check after what the order the autonum's were assigned in.

I put order in quotes because order is implied by some field (eg autonum). If there is no autonum, we cannot expect the results in any particular way

Comment: I would have though that it would order in the way i insert them but its now how it happen.

Comment: I modify a column to be autonum and in delphi, i increment that row for each one i insert and when i check the access file directly with MS Access, the autonum column is not in the correct order. I can just from 85664 to 85718 and i will see the missing row later in the file

Comment: How to write my sql command in delphi so that the autonum column will be fill automatically with a number without me needing to add an integer value in that column?

Comment: You might best do this from within Access. A SQL command such as "ALTER TABLE tablename ADD myfiield int autonumber" might get it